# return value from json session to use outside of session

Tags: json, swift

I've searched for how to do this but something just isn't making sense for me and I can't do it. All I need to do is get data out of my json session (if thats what you call it). I started programming about 3 weeks ago so I need lay mans terms please. I realize this is probably going to get marked as a duplicate but most of the answers on this / related topics are for other languages and I barely understand swift so they don't help me much.

I've spent hours trying to find the answer and since I'm new I don't know if what I'm searching for is even the right thing to be searching for. I've also tried reading the iOS developer library but either I don't understand what it's telling me or I haven't found the right section because I still can't figure this out.  Please try to explain this instead of sending me to read other resources.

here is my function

```
func parseData() {

let urlString = "http://heroesjson.com/heroes.json"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    guard let responseData = data else { return }
    var json: [[String: AnyObject]]!

    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    }
    catch {
        //handle error
    }

    var arrayToReturn = [Hero]()
    for element in json {
        let hero = Hero(fromDictionary: element as! [String: AnyObject])
        arrayToReturn.append(hero)
    }
    }.resume()//Closes Session.dataTaskWithURL
} //Closes parseData()
```

the goal is to get the json variable in my do statement so I can parse it outside of the function or get my "arrayToReturn" so I can save it to a global variable that I use.

If I understand correctly I can't just assign the value (arrayToReturn) to my global variable (heroes) because this is an asynchronous request so it just returns nil because the command is called before the request is finished. I think I have to use a completion handler or callback function. I don't really understand the difference between them and don't understand **how** or **where** to implement them.

Also, I don't understand this code very much either, I just know it's necessary to get what I want.

```
session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

"(data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)" looks like parameters but they don't seem to be attached to a function so that doesn't make sense to me

"-> Void" Doesn't make sense to me because -> means return whatever follows, but void indicates to me that its returning nothing, so why not just leave it out all together?

"-> Void **in**" What what is the significance of in here? what does it mean / signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and read about [Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). To use a value outside of it, you'd need to pass it to another closure.

```
func parseData(callback: (heroes: [Hero]) -> Void) {

let urlString = "http://heroesjson.com/heroes.json"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    guard let responseData = data else { return }
    var json: [[String: AnyObject]]!

    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    }
    catch {
        //handle error
    }

    var arrayToReturn = [Hero]()
    for element in json {
        let hero = Hero(fromDictionary: element as! [String: AnyObject])
        arrayToReturn.append(hero)
    }

    callback(heroes: arrayToReturn)
    }.resume()//Closes Session.dataTaskWithURL
} //Closes parseData()
```

And you'd call it:

```
parseData { heroes in
    // do something with the array
}
```

Comment: I read that entire section earlier today and I still don't understand how to do what i'm asking...which is why i resorted to asking here. If you could be more specific about which part that might help.

Comment: I edited my response, maybe it makes sense now. If it helps, please make sure to mark it as the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code and it works. I just have to find out how to run this code at the beginning of my program before the rest of it starts because the program needs all the data that is populated from this json parse